# SwiftUI Transactions: Making a button that either animates or is still, based on external state

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, repeat

I'm trying to make a view that conditionally animates (repeating forever) based on the state of another view.

This below button does it all in one view... but that state is all *internal*. I want it to be *external*.

```swift
struct ButtonBouncerView: View {
    @State var active: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .scaleEffect(active ? 1.08: 1)
            .animation(Animation.default.repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: active)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .onTapGesture {
                useTransaction()
            }
            .onAppear {
                active = true
            }
    }

    func useTransaction() {
        var transaction = Transaction()
        transaction.disablesAnimations = active ? true : false

        withTransaction(transaction) {
            withAnimation {
                active.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to do it like this, using the Transactions API. However, this just has the effect of doing weird animations when I tap, basically doing some sort of weird wobbling like motion.

```swift
struct OutsideControllableButtonView: View {
    @State private var active: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            OutsideControllableButtonScaler(active: $active)
            Button(action: { // CONTROLLER BUTTON!
                active.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Control Button")
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.green)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}

struct OutsideControllableButtonScaler: View {
    // When Active, the button
    @Binding var active: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .scaleEffect(active ? 1.08: 1)
            .animation(Animation.default.repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: active)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .onChange(of: active) { newValue in
                var transaction = Transaction(animation: newValue ? Animation.default.repeatForever(autoreverses: true) : nil)
                transaction.disablesAnimations = true
                withTransaction(transaction) {
                    self.active = newValue
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like below, where you're setting what animation you want to use based on `active`.  I don't believe you can stop the repeatForever animation by setting it to nil, you actually need to update it to default...

Alternatively, you could write an extension on `Animation` to make this a little cleaner/reusable. But at a quick test, the below starts and stops the animation as I believe you are attempting to do.

```
struct OutsideControllableButtonView: View {
    @State private var active: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            OutsideControllableButtonScaler(active: $active)
            Button(action: { // CONTROLLER BUTTON!
                self.active.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Control Button")
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.green)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}

struct OutsideControllableButtonScaler: View {
    // When Active, the button
    @Binding var active: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .scaleEffect(active ? 1.08 : 1)
            .animation(active ? Animation.default.repeatForever(autoreverses: true) : .default, value: active)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, so it seems that none of the Transaction stuff was actually necessary, and that you can just get the behavior by replacing the animation. This is good to know. Thanks @valosip